# Did the ancient Greeks know that "most" cube roots are irrational?

Tags: mathematics, ancient-greece, numbers

It is common knowledge that the Pythagoreans discovered irrational numbers (or incommensurability), for example if the hypotenuse of an isosceless right triangle is compared with one of the legs or while investigating the pentagram.  However, what I've read is always about square roots.  Now, the famous problem of doubling the cube involves cube roots and Wikipedia claims that Hero of Alexandria knew a method to approximate cube roots.  My question is: Did the Greek mathematicians know that "most" cube roots (for example the cube root of two) are also irrational?  Or at least some?  Any sources?

Comment: An interesting question you ask. The Pythagoreans, to my knowledge, knew/found out the square root of 2 is irrational, but I doubt that they knew *most square roots* are irrational. Also, the Greeks were mainly geometers and numbers were treated as *lengths* and it's rather odd that the Pythagoreans were, as historical records show (they even murdered a guy), loathe to accept *irrational numbers*. Also, where in geometry then would a Pythagorean encounter a *cube root* calculation? Beats me. The length of the sides of a cube given its volume?

Comment: Pythagoreans had deep belief that the universe was ruled by simple ratios.

Comment: @AgentSmith My question was about Greek mathematicians in general, not specifically about the Pythagoreans.  The Pythagoreans problably only knew about the square root of two.  But later generations certainly knew more - see for example book 10 of Euclid's Elements or, a lot earlier, Theodorus of Cyrene.  As for where a question about cube roots could come up, see my remark about the doubling of the cube or Euclid about solid figures.

Comment: It depends on what "know" means. The divisibility argument in Euclid works for all imperfect squares and is easily extended to imperfect cubes and fractions, but our extant sources do not have this done explicitly (Theodorus is mentioned by Plato to do some square roots by a different method, see [McCabe](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690123)). Greeks "knew" that cube cannot be duplicated even with straightedge and compass, i.e. is not even a quadratic irrational in modernized terms, this is why they used conic sections or neusis. But, of course, they had no proofs.

Comment: Lemmermeyer on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/49670/51484) names Stifel as the first to explicitly mention irrationality of cube roots in 1544.